# skip task when a value not found on a variable construct with json

Tags: ansible

The playbook is:

```
---
- hosts: ahgroup
  become: yes
  vars:
    volumes_group_name: "{{ ansible_hostname|upper }}_VG01"
    device: /dev/sdc
    partition_number: 1

  tasks:
  - name: Create partition
    parted:
     device: "{{device}}"
     number: "{{partition_number}}"
     label: gpt
     state: present

  - name: Check pvs busy
    shell: pvs --noheadings "{{device}}{{partition_number}}" --reportformat json 2>/dev/null
    register: vgmon

  - debug: msg="{{ vgmon.stdout }}"

  - name: Create volumes group
    lvg:
     vg: "{{volumes_group_name}}"
     pvs: "{{device}}{{partition_number}}"
     pesize: "4"
    when: (vgmon.stdout | from_json).report[].pv[].vg_name == ''
```

I need to skip the task if the volume group already exists on this PV.
The command that is used in "Check pvs busy" tasks produces output when VG is configured on it:

```
# pvs --noheadings /dev/sdc1 --reportformat json 2>/dev/null
  {
      "report": [
          {
              "pv": [
                  {"pv_name":"/dev/sdc1", "vg_name":"DATA_VG01", "pv_fmt":"lvm2", "pv_attr":"a--", "pv_size":"<256.00g", "pv_free":"<101.00g"}
              ]
          }
      ]
  }
```

When pvs does not exist on it, then in *json* attribute is empty: `"vg_name":""`

How should the *when* condition look like to get it working properly and skip VG creation task when VG is already on remote?

When I run the playbook now,I get:

```
$ ansible-playbook test2.yaml

PLAY [databases] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
Friday 28 May 2021  16:10:45 +0200 (0:00:00.070)       0:00:00.070 ************
ok: [192.168.1.101]

TASK [Create partition] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
Friday 28 May 2021  16:10:48 +0200 (0:00:03.134)       0:00:03.204 ************
ok: [192.168.1.101]

TASK [Check pvs busy] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
Friday 28 May 2021  16:10:49 +0200 (0:00:01.203)       0:00:04.407 ************
changed: [192.168.1.101]

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Friday 28 May 2021  16:10:50 +0200 (0:00:01.132)       0:00:05.540 ************
ok: [192.168.1.101] => {
    "msg": "  {\n      \"report\": [\n          {\n              \"pv\": [\n                  {\"pv_name\":\"/dev/sdc1\", \"vg_name\":\"DATA_VG01\", \"pv_fmt\":\"lvm2\", \"pv_attr\":\"a--\", \"pv_size\":\"<256.00g\", \"pv_free\":\"<101.00g\"}\n              ]\n          }\n      ]\n  }"
}

TASK [Create volumes group] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
Friday 28 May 2021  16:10:50 +0200 (0:00:00.121)       0:00:05.662 ************
fatal: [192.168.1.101]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '(vgmon.stdout | from_json).report[].pv[].vg_name == ''' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ((vgmon.stdout | from_json).report[].pv[].vg_name == ''): list object has no element ()\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/otds/ansible-pipeline/test2.yaml': line 24, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Create volumes group\n    ^ here\n"}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ vgmon.stdout.report|json_query('[].pv[].vg_name') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - DATA_VG01
```

Use this list to test the item, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ volumes_group_name }} is in the list."
      when:  volumes_group_name in vgmon.stdout.report|
                                   json_query('[].pv[].vg_name')
      vars:
        volumes_group_name: DATA_VG01
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: DATA_VG01 is in the list.
```

This task will be skipped

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ volumes_group_name }} is not in the list."
      when:  volumes_group_name not in vgmon.stdout.report|
                                       json_query('[].pv[].vg_name')
      vars:
        volumes_group_name: DATA_VG01
```

---

(As a sidenote)

Make your life easier and use the yaml callback plugin, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: vgmon.stdout
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  vgmon.stdout:
    report:
    - pv:
      - pv_attr: a--
        pv_fmt: lvm2
        pv_free: <101.00g
        pv_name: /dev/sdc1
        pv_size: <256.00g
        vg_name: DATA_VG01
```

Comment: unfortunatelly it still fails with error: {"msg": "The conditional check 'volumes_group_name not in vgmon.stdout.report| json_query('[].pv[].vg_name')' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if volumes_group_name not in vgmon.stdout.report| json_query('[].pv[].vg_name') %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable